# Ensure web site cache is cleared on Internet Explorer when site is updated

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, tomcat, grails

I'm running a website using Grails on a Tomcat server. When I update the website pages, Firefox applies the updates correctly, but Internet Explorer seems to keep the cached values until I explicitly delete the temporary internet files. How do I make sure Internet Explorer users have the up-to-date web pages when the site gets updated?

Edit: I tested on Internet Explorer 9, but I assume previous versions have the same issue.

Edit 2: The problem is only happening with css and javascript includes.

Answer (score 1):

Well the most reliable way to do that it to tell the browser to reload all the css and javascript resources afresh ignoring the cache and in order to do this you should change the names of your css and javascript resources so that browser knows that it needs to reload them.

Though it might be tedious/impractical task for you to rename all the css and javascript resources every time you deploy a new build on production, you can use the

> ui-performance-plugin

for this purpose. It plugin, if configured correctly, makes sure when ever you create a new war it will append the current revision number from the repository to the file name and hence file names are changed. Limitation with this will be you will have to update all the references to your css and javascript files in gsp's to include them using the plugin's tablib rather than directly (so that while renaming the files it also replaces the corresponding references in the gsp files).

Also, this plugin can provide you a number of other features which might help you increasing the speed of web application. For more detailed features of plugin [click here](http://grails.org/plugin/ui-performance)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A more modern answer similar to Bala's above is to use the [Resources](http://grails.org/plugin/resources) plugin (included by default in Grails 2.0+, and available for Grails 1.3+ as a plugin) combined with the [Cached Resources](http://grails.org/plugin/cached-resources) plugin.

The Cached Resources plugin does a similar thing to UI Performance, in that it replaces all the static content links with special hash-based links.  What's better than UI Performance is that the links are based on the file content, so they *aren't* updated if the content of the static item doesn't change.  This is great, because your user won't be forced to re-download a file that hasn't actually changed.

The Resources plugin allows you to define all your resources as modules - which is a very powerful way to describe the CSS, images, and JavaScript used in your application.  The [manual](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/guide/1.%20Overview.html#1.1%20Quick%20Start) is very well written, and will help you get started.  It requires several steps:

- Added `<r:layoutResources/>` to your layout in the `<head>` tag **and** just before the closing `</body>` tag.
- Replacing all (or some) of your `<link/>`, `<script/>`, and `<img/>` tags with the `<r:require/>`, `<r:script/>`, and `<r:img/>` equivalents.
- Even better, move your CSS and JavaScript dependencies into the `ApplicationResources.groovy` file, and set them up as reusable modules.

It's actually pretty quick to make the switch, and once you do, you'll be able to take advantage of other plugins, such as [Zipped Resources](http://grails.org/plugin/zipped-resources) (enables GZip compression) and [YUI Minify Resources](http://grails.org/plugin/yui-minify-resources), which minifies CSS and JS files.